# Visual studio Code : Import "pandas" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

[image: error screenshot]

Hi there,
I have installed Python 3.10.8 from Microsoft store and installed Pandas (via pip), but still got this message.
Thanks

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your system.  Pip installed pandas for one version of Python, but VS Code is configured to use a different version.

Comment: Don't post images of text, especially not of error messages. Copy the text here

Answer (score 1):

The kernel version displayed in the upper right corner of your picture is 3.9.10

Please click it to switch it to 3.10.8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to not having the correct Python interpreter selected in VsCode.
Press **Cntrl+Shift+P**, search for **Select Python Interpreter** and try to change between the options.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can have to install http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

and then you can just do

> conda install pandas

you have all the instruction in the next web page.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/getting_started/install.html